# activerecord-sqlserver-adapter seems to have broken devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, activerecord, devise

I have been working on a rails app for about 2 weeks that has worked fine every time I run it on my local machine. However, today I connected the app to sqlserver (instead of the default sqlite db) with the activerecord-sqlserver-adapter gem.

I was able to successfully connect to the db, but now I receive a `undefined method 'email' for <User>` on my DeviseSession#new page.

Does anyone know why changing db adapters would cause devise to break?

Answer (score 1):

Because you did not migrate the database after switching the adapter, so the attribute does not exist.

Comment: I am connecting to an existing db that definitely has the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I set the table names within my models and forgot their schema prefix.